# Method reads properly but the written text file only has 1 line. Is \n not working?

Tags: python-3.x, methods

1. The goal is to extract specific data from a text file under a folder
2. then write that data into another file under different folder
3. The extraction part works, save to variables and can even print them
4. The rises when you try to write them to a file
5. The file is empty
6. Need to write in this format
   {self.title};;;{self.author};;;{self.release_date};;;
   {self.last_update_date};;;{self.language};;;{self.producer};;;{self.book_path}

```
# This class includes all the operations related to a book
class Operation:
    """
    Need to include these class variables
    book_title_list (List of all books titles such as “[title1, title2, title3, …]”)
    book_info_dict = “{title1: obj1, title2:obj2, title3:obj3…….}”)
    """
    book_folder_path = './data/books_data/'
    book_info_path = './data/result_data/books.txt'

    def extract_book_info(self):
        directory_files = os.listdir(self.book_folder_path)  # Stores the .txt files under books_data folder
        try:
            for i in directory_files:
                with open(f'{self.book_folder_path}/{i}', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
                    f_contents = f.readlines()
                    f_line_free = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), f_contents))
                    f_lists = f_line_free[10:22] # Slicing only the required elements of the list
                    """
                    Extracting only the necessary part and storing them
                    under proper variables
                    """
                    title = f_lists[0]
                    author = f_lists[2]
                    release_date = f_lists[4]
                    last_update_date = f_lists[5]
                    language = f_lists[7]
                    producer = f_lists[11]

                    """
                    Extracting the desired values
                    """
                    title_data = title[7:]
                    author_data = author[8:]
                    release_date_data = release_date[14:]
                    last_update_date_data = last_update_date[24:-1]
                    language_data = language[10:]
                    producer_data = producer[13:]
                    print(title_data)
                with open(self.book_info_path, 'w', encoding="utf8") as wf:
                    wf.write(f'{title_data};;;{author_data};;;{release_date_data};;;'
                             f'{last_update_date_data};;;{language_data};;;{producer_data};;;{self.book_info_path}\n')
            return True

        except FileNotFoundError:
            return False
        except Exception:
            return False
```

Comment: You should provide a sample .txt file and enough code to reproduce the problem. 
 Instantiate and call the function, for example.  Remove the try/except to make sure you aren't generating and masking an exception or at least check if your function is returning `False`.  I made a mockup of a .txt file that met your slicing requirements and it worked properly, so you need to make a [mcve].

Comment: @MarkTolonen Bro, I tested all of the above, all is good but it doesn't write to file :( Edit: It works but I get 1 line. I have like 100 files in the folder so it should be 100 files

Comment: So edit your question and add a sample input file so we can reproduce the problem.  I made a file and it worked, so give us **your** file.  Did you remove the try/except?

Comment: the wf.write () part --> is \n not used properly? Because I am getting only 1 line

Comment: You open the file as 'w' which starts with a new, empty file each time.  Open with 'a' (append) or open the file once outside the `for` loop.

Comment: I know that too but I saw on stack that putting \n at the end create new lines lol

Comment: Thank you. Also, can I update a class variable from the method? i.e. book_title_list --> from my code

Comment: `self.book_title_list` updates the *instance*, `Operation.book_title_list` updates the *class* (all instances).

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask